# Replace Variable In String Replaces Wrong Character

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

Good day. I have a script being executed off an input which replaces part of a string. It works as it should; except, when two underscore parted strings contain the same character. The picture below, I want the second character "M" to be replaced with "M1" not the first.

Is there a way to specify or declare exactly where you want to replace a variable inside a string with many of the same characters? Any help is most appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. So, you want the final string to be in the example PH_WM_M1_LT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to split and then reassemble with the replaced values, rather than replacing everything in the value:

```
var spl = getVal.split('_');
for(var idx =0 ; idx < spl.length; idx++ ) {
    var b = spl[idx].replace(/\d+/g,''); // remove all numbers?
    spl[idx] = b + afVal;
}
rep = spl.join('_');
```

Comment: I do need to split, replace, then reassemble due to my current situation with respect to ordering and combinations. Thanks.

Comment: this is actually more secure. especially when I run into the scenario like e.g. PH_INF_M_M       my input reaches the first still. By splitting first and knowing the index that I need to change, I don't need to worry about similar string characters with an underscore before it or not. Thanks.

Comment: can do without the for loop. Same concept. Thanks.

Comment: good. It assumed your code was taken from a loop because of the ind variable.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to simply add underscore in the replace string  if that is how you expect M to appear in the string.

```js
var a = "PH_WM_M_LT"
console.log(a.replace("_M", "_M1"));
```

Comment: I like this since its a simple fix. However, it presents a few additional nuances that I wasn't anticipating. This is a dynamic combination and it may not always be presented with an underscore before. (e.g. PH) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Forgot, I had an index that will let me know which order its in the array. Quick If statement and good to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to specify a specific location, you could find the location using *indexof* in the string, for example getVal.indexof("_M"). Then you could do something where you use substrings then specifically add the value like below

```
function insertString(insertPoint, sValue, insertValue)
    {
         var n = sValue.length;
         var frontHalf = sValue.substring(0,insertPoint);
         var backHalf = sValue.substring(insertPoint,n);
         return frontHalf + insertValue + backHalf;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, a few lines above my screen shot has an indexOf so you are absolutely right!. Thanks